# Why is the sum of the sample autocorrelations of a stationary series equal to -1/2?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

I cannot grasp my head around this property of stationary series and the autocorrelation function. I have to prove that

\begin{align}
\sum_{h=1}^{n-1}\hat\rho(h)=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Where $\hat\rho(h)=\displaystyle\frac{\hat\gamma(h)}{\hat\gamma(0)}$ and $\hat\gamma(h)$ is the autocovariance function

\begin{align}
\hat\gamma(h) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(X_t-\bar{X})(X_{t+h}-\bar{X})
\end{align}

Hopefully someone can help me out with a proof, or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: by subtracting a constant from all the $X_t$, which will change none of the $\hat\gamma(h)$, you may assume $0=\sum_{t=1}^nX_t$.  Square that and look for pieces that match your two sums.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that subtracting a constant does not affect any of the $\hat{\gamma}(h)$, but I don't see why it allows me to assume that the sum of the series is equal to 0.

Comment: Subtract exactly the constant that makes $\sum X_t$ equal to 0. Now your $\hat\gamma$ is simplified (because the new $X_t$'s have mean 0) and the terms are much easier to play with (but without loss of generality).

Comment: It appears it should be $1/(n-h)$ rather than $1/n$

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I believe both versions are valid estimators of the autocovariance function with the same asymptotic properties but I read somewhere that $1/n$ is preferred. (The reason is that the matrix $\hat{\gamma}(i-j)$ is positive semi-definite, I am not a mathematician so I can't really explain this reason!)

Comment: Assume that you have a sample of size $n=100$. You want to etsimate $\hat \gamma(98)$. You can consider only two products (and assume for simplicity that the series has sample mean zero) , $x_1x_{99}$ and $x_2x_{100}$. Are you going to divide them by $100$ or by $2$?

Comment: Yes you make a very valid point. The preference is argued in Brockwell and Davis, 1991, p. 221, for those interested. And for cases like the one you mentioned $1/n$ is not the best version, of course for practical purposes we are not likely to use the sample autocovariances when $h$ is close to $n$.

Comment: Please see: Hossein Hassani, Random Operators and Stochastic Equations, Volume 17, Issue 2, [Pages 125–130](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/rose.2009.17.issue-2/rose.2009.008/rose.2009.008.xml); & Hossein Hassani, Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications Volume 389, Issue 8, 15 April 2010, [Pages 1601-1606](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437109010644).

Comment: For more information see the following papers: Hassani, Hossein (August 2009). "Sum of the sample autocorrelation function". Random Operators and Stochastic Equations. 17 (2): 125-130. doi:DOI: 10.1515/ROSE.2009.008 Hassani, Hossein (April 2010). "A note on the sum of the sample autocorrelation function". Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications. 389 (8): 1601--1606. doi:10.1016/j.physa.2009.12.050. ISSN 0378-4371.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by representing the sum $S$ using the definition of the autocorrelation function:

\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \hat{\rho}(h) = \sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(X_t-\bar{X})(X_{t+h}-\bar{X})}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}(X_t-\bar{X})^2}\right)
\end{equation}

Denominator does not depend on $h$ so we can simplify and move the front $\sum$ to the numerator, which gives us:
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{\sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h} (X_t-\bar{X})(X_{t+h}-\bar{X})}{\sum_{t=1}^{n} (X_t-\bar{X})^2}
\end{equation}

Now consider the denominator. How do we represent in so we get an expression similar to the numerator? Set $Y_t=X_t-\bar{X}$. Then $\sum_{t=1}^{n}Y_t=0.$ The denominator here is $\sum_{t=1}^{n}Y_t^{2}$.
We know that $\sum_{t=1}^{n}Y_t^{2} = \left(\sum_{t=1}^{n}Y_t\right)^2 - 2\sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h}Y_t Y_{t+h}$, i.e. subtracting all unique pairs $\times$ 2.  Because $\sum_{t=1}^{n}Y_t=0$, it follows that $\sum_{t=1}^{n}Y_t^{2} =  - 2\sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h}Y_t Y_{t+h}$.

Plugging back in terms of X, the denominator becomes $- 2\sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(X_t-\bar{X})(X_{t+h}-\bar{X})$. Then,

\begin{equation}
S=\frac{\sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(X_t-\bar{X})(X_{t+h}-\bar{X})}{- 2\sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h}(X_t-\bar{X})(X_{t+h}-\bar{X})}= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank very much, I'll accept this answer in a moment, I just have one final question. Everything is clear to me except this part: $\sum_{t=1}^{n}Y_t^{2} = \left(\sum_{t=1}^{n}Y_t\right)^2 - 2\sum_{h=1}^{n-1} \sum_{t=1}^{n-h}Y_t Y_{t+h}$. I don't understand how we are able to include the double summation here, I assume it is a property or identity of the summation?

Comment: To see this, try to expand $(\sum_{t=1}^n Y_t)^2$. You get the sum of $Y_t^2$, then the rest of the terms are of type $Y_iY_j$ for $i\neq j$, each of which occurs twice in the expansion due to symmetry. Now, the double summation comes from enumerating these pairs in the following way: For $Y_1$, we count $Y_2, Y_3$, etc. For $Y_2$, we count $Y_3,Y_4$ etc., until we reach $Y_{n-1}$ for the final pair $Y_{n-1}Y_n$.